# Conversion failed when converting from character string to uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query which selects a table based on the provided uniqueidentifier Id so when i provides Id to a value it returns the result but if i am passing it like below i am getting an error message. Please suggest how to use Convert or Cast in this case to resolve this issue.
Thanks

```
SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE ID=''
```

Comment: Please show the value of the string you're trying to convert. How does `WHERE ID=''` make any sense?

Comment: Can you clarify; if `ID` is a a column of type `uniqueidentifier` it can be null but it can never contain `''` so looking for it is pointless

Comment: Yes Id is a column of type uniqueidentifier and if you type above query i have given it raise an error.

Comment: @user1399377 it raises an error because it tries to convert what your searching for (the empty string '') into a uniqueidentifier; there is no way to do that, a uniqueidentifier is either null or a full 36 character/16 byte jobby - look in your table, there will be no "empty" ID fields

Comment: Yes @Aex i am pretty agree with you ..but i hope may be Convert or Cast method can solve my issue.

Comment: But to look for what? what's the uid equivalent of `''` ? If you want to look for a uid and the value you searching for is *not* a uid, don't do the search in the 1st place

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `@id` is a string parameter, and that the `ID` column is not nullable, you could do something silly like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE ID = COALESCE(NULLIF(@id, ''), ID);
```

But really you should be passing `NULL` if there is no value, not an empty string. This shouldn't be a string parameter in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments on this answer, the solution should be something like this (in pseudo-code):

```
if textbox1.Text.ToString().Equals('') {
    SELECT * FROM TBL
}
else {
    SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE ID='"+textbox1.text+"' 
}
```

You may do the `IF` in the C# application.

Comment: Actully i think i have not posted my question correctly. well the scenario is i have a textbox in my c# application which takes Id as a parameter so my query is like SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE ID='"+textbox1.text+"' so if i am not sending any value in the textbox and clicks on the search button it makes my query like SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE ID='' . So that is my scenario. please suggest how to handle it

Comment: Check if the value is `''` and if so, don't make the query?

Comment: Is there a possibility that user doesn't enter uniqueidentifier, instead he just enters empty string? What results do you want to retrieve then?

Comment: So @aF..is that the only solution??

Comment: @user1399377 it's the correct one. It also avoids an SQL call improving performace.